# Database app html templates

Tags: html, css, templates

Does anyone know of a good place that has some HTML templates for database app. I have tried dataface but it's bit more than I need and I would rather write the sql myself for specific operations. Something that has the css sorted for listing results and navbar or menu system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search google for admin templates rather than just website templates. Plenty to choses from. Simpla Admin is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

How about [DataTables (jQuery plugin)](http://datatables.net/) for the listings? This is a very broad question. The menu/navbar is likely going to be language specific: what platform are you using?

Comment: More a layout question really. Just want a GUI ready to go so I can add the calls required. Think nav bar left hand side table results right hand side. Sorting and editing aren't required.